# How to get notification when a field is created or deleted on Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have 3 collections: `Therapy`, `Users`, and `Transaction` at the top level.
[image]

Below `Users` there are `Customer` and `Therapist`. The customer will created a `Transaction` with the selected therapist.

When customers order something, the field is created and the therapist will get a notification. Both the Therapist and Customer may cancel the transaction, which will mark the field as deleted. Upon deletion, both will receive notifications.

How i can do this?

I can't provide sample code since I don't know where to start.

Comment: Your question is very broad, but you should look into Cloud Functions for writing backend code that triggers when a document is changed in Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Start here https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events ?

Comment: Yeah sorry, but it because i dont even know what i dont know about it. I will ask a specific question once i know what i needed to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Cloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)** provide a mechanism for handling Firestore events.

> With Cloud Functions, you can handle events in Cloud Firestore with no
>   need to update client code. You can make Cloud Firestore changes via
>   the DocumentSnapshot interface or via the Admin SDK.
>
> In a typical lifecycle, a Cloud Firestore function does the following:
>
> 1. Waits for changes to a particular document.
> 2. Triggers when an event occurs and performs its tasks (see [What can I do with Cloud Functions?](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases) for examples of use cases).
> 3. Receives a data object that contains a snapshot of the data stored in the specified document. For `onWrite` or `onUpdate` events, the data object contains two snapshots that represent the data state before and after the triggering event.